# Understanding $T\subseteq T' \implies T = T'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, intuition

I would like to clear up a confusion which might be trivial. In a proof  the author proved $T = T'$ as following:

The author showed if $x \in T$ then $x \in T'$, the next line is -

> ... proving that $T\subseteq  T'$. As a result $T = T'$.

Reasoning:

If for any $x$, it exists in both set $T$ and $T'$, then we can directly write $T = T'$, and if $T = T'$ by definition we can say $T \subset T'$.

Full Context:
[image]

Confusion:

Then why do author write first  $T\subseteq  T'$ then $T = T'$ (notice the sequence)?

$T\subseteq  T'$ means either $T\subset  T'$ or $T=  T'$, it looks like at this point author does not know what should the case exactly but then based what he writes $T =T'$ in the next line?

If $T=T'$ is written for the reasoning given above then $T\subseteq  T'$ is unnecessary, why do author write $T\subseteq  T'$?

What is the significance?

Another example is that often I found that we can say directly that $H_{i+1}= \rm Ker \; g$ but author(s) used $H_{i+1}\subseteq \rm Ker \; g$ ([see Question 1 in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4256432/850314)), obviously $H_{i+1}= \rm Ker \; g$ does not contradict $H_{i+1}\subset \rm Ker \; g$ but why do author go for the weaker statement?

Comment: What are $T$ and $T'$? Perhaps $T' \supset T$ was assumed?

Comment: The context  here might be important.  It's obviously not enough to know that $T\subset T'$ to conclude that $T = T'$. If you can prove *both* $T\subset T'$ and $T'\subset T$, then $T=T'$.  Perhaps there's some extra assumption (or structure that you're not telling us) that guarantees that $T'\subset T$; or perhaps that was already proved earlier.

Comment: Absent context, there is nothing to be said.  Obviously there are situations in which $A$ is a subset of $B$ but $A$ is not equal to $B$.  Presumably the author has more information in mind.

Comment: @fwd nothing is assumed like that, I have added the complete proof, plz see again.

Comment: If $T'$ is meant to denote the commutator subgroup of $T$, then it is obvious that $T'$ is contained in $T$.

Comment: @lulu yes, in that case  it should be like $T' \subset T$ by definition of subgroup and it was showed that $T \subset T'$, thus $T' = T$, but why do write $T' \subseteq T$? because untill next line we don't know the equality.

Comment: I don't understand.  For any group $G$ we have $G'\subseteq G$.  If for some particular $G$ you can show that $G\subseteq G'$ then of course you must have equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it seems the issue is that you need to return to the definition of $T'$ and make sure you understand it thoroughly. The author proved $T \subseteq T'$ and then immediately concluded $T = T'$ because it should so obvious to the reader that also $T'\subseteq T$ that it does not need to be written.

To be clear, you should not be discouraged if this is not obvious to you. Learning always takes time and I think all of us have at some point misunderstood some concept only to realize it later. Omitting an explicit mention of these types of "simple" statements in textbooks can often signal to the reader the level of understanding they probably need before progressing.

Answer (score 0):

When we prove all the elements of $T$ is also elements of $T'$, it has two meanings:

1. $T=T'$ (note it does not contradict $T\subset T'$),
2. $T \subset T'$,

these two meanings can be written in a single line as-
$$T \subseteq T'$$

You constructed $T'$ by taking elements $(I+ E_{ik}), (I + E_{kj})$ from $T$ and multiplying those elements (to construct each element of the $T'$) in the following way:

$$(I+ E_{ik})(I + E_{kj}) (I + E_{ik})^{-1}(I + E_{kj})^{-1}$$

Above type of multiplication to construct each element of the $T'$ makes $T'$ a commutator subgroup, by definition. Since,  commutator subgroup $T'$ is constructed by multiplying elements of $T$ in a specific way

(i.e. $(I+ E_{ik})(I + E_{kj}) (I + E_{ik})^{-1}(I + E_{kj})^{-1}$), so $T'$ is the commutator subgroup of $T$, i.e. $T' \subset T$.

We have showed $T' \subset T$ and all the elements of $T$ are also elements of $T'$, so we take the first meaning or possibility of $T \subseteq T'$, thus, $T'=T$.